# How to insert values in mysql database if one of the column is auto increment using prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, sqlexception

```
public String put(){
         this.query = "INSERT INTO user_registration VALUES('default', '?' , '?' , '?' , '?' , '?' );";

    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt= Main.connection.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1,this.fullname);
        stmt.setString(2,this.username);
        stmt.setString(3,this.password);
        stmt.setString(4,this.email);
        stmt.setString(5,this.contact);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        return String.valueOf(SignupStatus.SUCCESS);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
        return String.valueOf(SignupStatus.FAILED);
    }
}
```

I am getting this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1372)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1385)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setString(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1752)
    at client_sharenow.Signup.put(Signup.java:29)
    at client_sharenow.Client_Request.run(Client_Request.java:40)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

Please help me out correcting the code.

Comment: I believe the question marks (parameters) in your SQL string should not have quotes next to them.

Comment: '?' will be treated as an value instead of placeholder. So try by removing the ' '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` placeholders must not be enclosed inside single quotes.
Also it's good practice to include in your statement the column names that will receive each of the supplied values.
If the 1st column is the auto increment column then you should omit it from the list, because its value will be supplied by MySql:

```
this.query = "INSERT INTO user_registration(fullname, username, password, email, contact) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
```

Change the column names to the actual ones.

Comment: It should also be noted that adding `''` confuses the PreparedStatement, which leads it to think that you are actually intending to insert '?' into that column

Comment: but now i am getting a diiferent exception:( that username cannot be null . can u help me in that?

Comment: If you have defined the column username as `NOT NULL` you must provide a non null value for `this.username`.

Comment: @alupi07 fine if it's solved and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark